# Python skipping one line after reading another

Tags: python, file

I am trying to read a file and write its contents in another file.

```
with open (inputFile, "r+") as file:
    with open (outputFile, "w+") as f:
        for line in file:
            data = file.readline()
            f.write(data)
    f.close()
file.close()
```

This is the code I used, but it seems to be skipping lines, so, if I have something like this in the input file:

```
'First line'
'Second line'
'Third line'
'Fourth line'
```

I get this in the outputFile:

```
'Second line'
'Fourth line'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could enumerate the lines, and check if index is even or odd

Comment: You iterate over file, reading one line at a time `for line in file:`, then you read next line (`data = file.readline()`). This is redundant. Just do `f.write(line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for line in file` iterates over each line already. `data = file.readline()` will yield another one from the file. Use one or the other.